# Salesforce Visualforce Website has Lots of Duplicate Content Pages

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, webservices, website-integration, duplicate-management

I have a website based on Visualforce (Salesforce, force pages) that has 11681 duplicate content pages. This is obviously terrible for SEO ranking. I clearly have not got nearly that many pages but each page has got human readable URL's such as: www.example.com/rest_of_url and URLs that redirect to those pages that is system generated such as: www.example.com/uy2342hjg323423

How do stop Google and Moz from seeing these pages as duplicate content? If nothing else I want to stop seeing it in Moz.com because it is frustrating to see.

MORE INFO AS REQUESTED:
Google and Moz both find duplicate content on the site with over 11000 pages. We don't even have that many pages. Some pages have 50 other pages of duplicate content - others have 3 or 4 pages. Google and Moz are therefore finding pages that don't exist or they are seeing URLs created by the Salesforce system and think its a different page with the same content as publicly facing pages

Comment: Perhaps better asked in a forum that specialises in SEO?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this in a concrete way. Wondering if you can be more specific. So for each actual page URL, there are *n* number of additional redirect URLs that point back to the same page? Is this using Sites? Communities? Can you give some mocked up examples?

Comment: Add more info to the original post